# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first on recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an application that just saves values pressing a `button`, this `button` opens a `dialog`, the problem here is that only i can press it one time, because after that it throws
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` and then crashes obviusly.
Also i have a `recyclerview` where all the values can be seen after adding them with the `button`.

Stacktrace:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.calcularpr, PID: 17510
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
> parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5235)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5036)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:657)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:475)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:233)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:279)
> at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:419)
> at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:313)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1009)
> at
> com.example.calcularpr.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:111)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
> at
> com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
> at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Java code :

```
package com.example.calcularpr;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase db;

     EditText prMark;

     ConstraintLayout layout;

RecyclerView recyclerView;

    DatabaseReference dbReference;
    ArrayList<Marks> data;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    View addView;

    Button addNewPrMain;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add,null);
        prMark = addView.findViewById(R.id.PbancaPR);
        dbReference = db.getReference("Pesos");
       addNewPrMain = findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);

       //RECYCLERVIEW
       data = new ArrayList<>();
       recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerViewAdapter adapter = new recyclerViewAdapter(this,data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        dbReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Marks marks = dataSnapshot.getValue(Marks.class);
                   data.add(marks);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }



            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        //RECYCLERVIEW

        //ADD PR BUTTON

       addNewPrMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

             AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
             dialogBuilder.setTitle("Añadir peso")
                     .setMessage("Añadir peso?")
                     .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             String prMarkData = prMark.getText().toString();
                             setData(prMarkData);
                         }
                     })
                     .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             dialog.cancel();
                         }
                     }).setView(addView)
                     .show();
      /*       if (v.getParent() != null) {
                   ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v);     //Tried this, but i think idk how to apply it correctly
               }
             layout.addView(v);  */




           }
       });

       //ADD PR
    }

    public void setData (String  peso) {
        Marks mark = new Marks(peso);
        dbReference.push().setValue(mark);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Marca añadida",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PR Banca "
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.952"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.975" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="528dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.561" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Recyclerview adapter:

```
package com.example.calcularpr;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class recyclerViewAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Marks> data;

    public recyclerViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Marks> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override

    public recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pr_card,parent,false);

        if (view.getParent() != null) {
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
        return  new recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Marks marks = data.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(marks.getWeight());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }


}
```

Recyclerview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content ">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_category_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="60"
                    android:textSize="48sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried different things, like checking    `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pr_card,parent,false);` ensuring  that the attach to root is false, also you can see in the java code that i tried to remove the view, but it did not work and maybe is because i dont know exactly how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be because you are reusing the addView instance. Try if this fixes the issue. Inside your click listener, create a new instance of the addView layout, just before setting it as the view for the dialog like this:

```
addNewPrMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Create new instance of addView
            View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Añadir peso")
                    .setMessage("Añadir peso?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String prMarkData = prMark.getText().toString();
                            setData(prMarkData);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }).setView(addView)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Correct, the instance had to be declared inside onclick and not outside, thanks!